# Override ASP.NET Authorization annotations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

Is there a way to override Authorize annotation in ASP.Net?

I'm using MVC and my controller is annotated with:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

The majority of actions in this controller are restricted to Admin users.

I would like to override one action method so that it becomes available to all users:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Users="*")]        
public Boolean Submit(FormCollection collection)
```

This is not working and users are being re-directed to login page. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Phil wrote a blog post how to apply a filter for every action except one. Here's the [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx).

Comment: There is [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx) by Rick Anderson that tries to solve the scenario you mentioned in an elegant way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve what you are trying to do by simply removing the attribute from controller and move it to methods only where needed.

Answer (score 1):

The class level attribute is being checked first, causing the behaviour you describe.

You would need to put the *less* restrictive role on the class attribute and then put the *more* restrictive role attribute on the relevant actions.